# Renew kerberos ticket, krenew not available

Tags: linux, fedora, kerberos

I'm fairly new to Linux. I have a shell script that runs daily off a cron. It requires a connection to sql server, which requires a valid kerberos ticket. I want to add logic to my script that renews the ticket before it runs but "krenew" doesn't exist on my machine. If I type `man krenew` I get back `No manual entry for krenew`. The command isn't there. Is there a package that needs to be installed? Something I'm missing? Could it have been removed?

Comment: where is that script from? I haven't encountered a `krenew` in Kerberos 5 as far as I can remember… `kinit` can be instructed to renew tickets. Maybe the script is really really old?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`krenew` is part of Russ Allbery's Kerberos tool `kstart`.

This is available at [https://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/kstart/](https://www.eyrie.org/%7Eeagle/software/kstart/)

I don't know if any distro includes this package, but you can compile it yourself from the provided sources.

Comment: `krenew` is part of the Fedora package collection: https://packages.fedoraproject.org/pkgs/kstart/kstart/, so `sudo dnf install kstart` (or for that matter `sudo dnf install /usr/bin/krenew`) should do it.